# Get Float Value from String

Tags: php, regex, string

I've a list of strings of the following type:

```
27 km
56.1 km
45 KM
96.2km
87 k
```

And I want to get the numeric value for each one. As you can see some of them are float values, and the suffix "km" sometimes is mistyped. The output I'm looking for is the following:

```
27
56.1
45
96.2
87
```

I've found regular expressions on the web that convert a string to number but they don't consider that some values can be float, how can I write a function or find a expression that meets my requirements?

Comment: In fact what I needed, you should post your comment as the answer

Comment: You already chose the answer. No big deal, unless you're planning on switching to mine. Hah.

Comment: there ya go. I won't be mad if you don't change the answer to me, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$var = floatval($float);` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

No need for a regex, just use [`floatval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php):

```
$float = floatval($string);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just `parseFloat()` them. `parseFloat()` converts strings that start with a number to a number and stop with the first non-numeric character.

`parseFloat('96.2 km')` = `96.2`

Comment: You're right. `floatval()` is the php equivalent. Been dealing with Javascript all day!

Comment: I do the same thing pretty often :)

Answer (score 0):

For these strings, you can use `/^\d+(\.\d+)?/`

Answer (score 0):

Floating point regex: 
[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+

Answer (score 0):

try this. works for me

```
try {    
    Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\b\d+(?:\.\d{0,}|)");    
    Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(subjectString);    
  while (matchResults.Success) {    
        // matched text: matchResults.Value    
        // match start: matchResults.Index    
        // match length: matchResults.Length    
        matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();    
    }     
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {    
    // Syntax error in the regular expression    
}
```

php way

```
preg_match_all('/\b\d+(?:\.\d{0,}|)/', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
    # Matched text = $result[0][$i];
}
```